# Python3 import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I have been confusing Python 3's difference from Python 2 about import.

If I have such a directory like this...

```
module_test/ ->
  a/hello.py
  lib/mad.py
```

And I want to import hello module from lib/mad.py

So I wrote code like this..

lib/mad.py

```
import a.hello
```

And I call python lib/mad.py ,but it happend ImportError.

I don't know why it happen like this.

Do you have any idea? I want to solve this question.

Sample repository is https://github.com/okamurayasuyuki/module_test/tree/master/lib . ##Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the `a` directory might not be on your Pythonpath. Post your exact stacktrace or you're not going to get any more useful help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that by running `mad.py` from the `module_test` directory, you guessed that Python would use your current directory as base for finding module `b`. To prove that it doesn't work, do the following:

1. Edit your `mad.py` script and add the following to the beggining of the script:

   ```
   import sys
   print(sys.path)
   exit()
   ```

   This will just print the search path Python uses to find modules you try to import and then exit.
2. Open the terminal, go to folder `/module_test` and run the following:

   ```
   > python lib/mad.py
   ```

   Now you should see the path dumped to the terminal. Note that the first entry in the list is the folder 'module_test/lib' not 'module_test' as you would have thought.

So, how do you solve the problem?

Simple: you just have to tell Python the correct directory it should be using to look for your modules. To do that, you must set the PYTHONPATH enviroment variable:

```
> export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/module_test
```

Now if you try to run your script, it should import `a.hello` as expected!

---

PS: You should read the official Python tutorial, specially chapter 6 which explains the concept of modules and packages:

http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

That should give you a basic understading and help you solve your problem.